# Changing what we say we allow questions about

Tags: support

Currently the site says this -

If you have a question about:

- Brewing processes
- Equipment used in the brewing process
- Brewed beverage appreciation
- Trouble shooting your brewing problems

and it is not about:

- Selling alcoholic drinks
- Buying commercially brewed products
- Irresponsible consumption of alcohol

then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

========================

I propose we change this to something like -

If you have a question about:

- Home alcoholic/fermented drink production
- Brewing processes
- Equipment used in the brewing process
- Brewed beverage appreciation
- Trouble shooting your brewing problems
- How to stay safe while doing the above

and it is not about:

- Irresponsible consumption of alcohol
- Buying commercially brewed products
- Selling alcoholic drinks

then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Comment: @thesquaregroot if you agree I am happy to change this on the help site. From the past discussion on solidifying policy change -farmersteve was in favour of making the site a little more broadly production focused to include all fermented/alcholic drink production.

Comment: @farmersteve do you also agree?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'll chime in.

Firstly, I'm not even sure where the site describes itself this way. Is whats shown to users before they join the community? I feel like a duntz being a long-time SO user and not knowing where to look for this :S

Second, (pedantic words to the right ->) I don't find the items here super compelling, either in the existing or proposed version. Do we normally have an issue of people talking about `Irresponsible consumption of alcohol`? Also- do we allow commercial-product-specific questions (`"Is <brand a> product better than <brand b> product?"` ). Also- I'm not sure if questions like `"I'm brewing a historic porter- does my recipe look correct?"` are allowed under these rules.

But- what is the goal of this splash info? Is it to clarify to outside users `"Am I in the right SE site to ask my question"`?

I like the effort people are starting to put in around the site, but I'm just not sure this is super meaningful. From what I can tell (genuine apologies to Mods if this is incorrect) there doesn't seem to be a ton of (or a big need for) heavy moderation here yet. If we actually closed duplicate questions the site would be a ghost town. Seriously- search "ginger bug" in the history- there's like 100 questions that could all be boiled down to 3. My point being- I'm worried that moderation for the sake of moderation will just drive away people and not benefit anyone except the ten power users we have.

Comment: Welcome to meta rob. I know what you are saying, I was a mod before I had even looked at the help section -  https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic we get a few moderation things from time to time on distillation and is this really fit for this site based on what it says here. As mods we tend to be far more lenient on this site than some other SE sites I am a member of. There is not a huge amount of modding needed, but making sure the stuff we have documented meets how things are run is important.

Comment: We do allow "Is X better than Y for Job Z type questions?" We do not allow people just advertising there product so "Did you know my widget is better than rob's?"

Comment: The question "I'm brewing a historic porter- does my recipe look correct?" would fall under "Brewing processes" as recipe formulation is a part of the process, or "Trouble shooting your brewing problems" as you are looking to accertain correctness, best to trouble shoot an issue beforte brewing 50l and waiting 4 weeks.

Comment: Ah, thanks for all the info! At the end- I think you got to my point. "Brewing processes" basically encompasses what we're aiming for, correct?. It seems you could reduce the entire list to that single item. But it really depends on what the exact purpose of this text is. I'm not sure if it's meant to inform potential users, existing users, or both. So, really you can sort of disregard this- it's not your job to manage my understanding :)